# How do I post an array and loop through it using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have an input field and when the user is typing something in, it immediately creates an array using jQuery `replace` function. The target is to send those values to PHP and perform a live search on a specific table in MySQL.

I got the part of the `input` field and the `ajax` call, **but I do not get the portion of the php loop done so far.**

**My target is to send this array serialized to php and use each item as variable.**

This is my jQuery and HTML [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lezx370L/1/).

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="row" style="padding:10px;">
    <input class="form-control" id="Input">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container rounded" id="smd" style="background-color:red; height:100px;display:none;">
<span>Search Results here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#Input").keyup(function() {
  var div = $('#smd');
  if ($("#Input").val().length > 0) {
    div.show();
    var source = $("#Input").val();
    var splittedSource = source.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' ');
    $.post('/url/to/page', splittedSource);

    console.log(splittedSource);
  } else {
    div.hide();
  }
});
```

This is how my string looks like:

```
["This", "is", "my", "string"]

0:"This"
1:"is"
2:"my"
3:"string"
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you tried just `print_r($_POST)` to see what you're getting on the server ?

Comment: You can't just put anything as the data argument, it has to be in a format that jQuery can use/transform into a proper request format like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, eg `$.post(url,{data:splittedSource})`

Comment: Noted. I have changed the `$.post` portion.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - actually you almost can. Sending just an array as `data` works fine, but you won't have a key to access it on the server, it would just populate `$_POST` with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to send as key/value pair or send and receive as `application/json`.

Right now you are only sending a value without a key that can be indexed by `$_POST`

Try

```
$.post('/url/to/page',{arr: splittedSource});
```

And in php

```
$arr = $_POST['arr'];//php array
```

To do it as json:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/url/to/page',
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(splittedSource)
   // other options
});
//php
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have the feeling that you could (or even should) handle such logic in your back end code, you might want to take a look at the manual on [how to use arrays in a form](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

This suggests that you should use a name that ends in `[]`. Since posting a form is simply using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` enctype by default, you can simply put the value `myarray[]=a&myarray[]=b`... etc in the request body and PHP will interpret it as the array value `$_POST['myarray']`.

Answer (score 0):

this is common format

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

you need to send correct format like

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

so your code need to update

```
$.post('/url/to/page', splittedSource);
```

to

```
$.post('/url/to/page',{data: splittedSource});
```

so you can get data using

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

you can use this also format

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

for more information about ajax post

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Almost, I did that part: `$.post('/url/to/page',{data: splittedSource});` but I send like multiple request, the data `array` changes immediatly and could have more than one element, so i need to do a `while` or `foreach` loop to get all those array elements into variable. This is the part I am not sure about.

Comment: I use an `Input` field, which the user entering values, all those values get separated by jquery `replace` function. I can't give every object a key, other than 0,1,2,3